# How do Anglicans interpret the great crowd (144,000) of Revelation 7?

Tags: exegesis, eschatology, revelation, anglicanism

What is an overview of the Anglican understandings of who/what are the 144000 of Revelation 7?

> After this I saw four angels standing at the four corners of the earth, holding back the four winds of the earth to prevent any wind from blowing on the land or on the sea or on any tree. <sup>2</sup> Then I saw another angel coming up from the east, having the seal of the living God. He called out in a loud voice to the four angels who had been given power to harm the land and the sea: <sup>3</sup> “Do not harm the land or the sea or the trees until we put a seal on the foreheads of the servants of our God.” <sup>4</sup> Then I heard the number of those who were sealed: 144,000 from all the tribes of Israel. ([Revelation 7](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation+7&version=NIV), NIV)

Comment: I checked 'The Mystery of Salvation' by the Church of England Doctrine Commission but the passage does not seem to be referenced.

Comment: @EleventhDoctor thanks for researching it for me.  seems to have stumped everyone this question.  :)

Comment: Your title seems to say that the great crowd and the 144k are same group  however if one group is innumerable and another is a set figure they are 2 separate groups

Comment: @David The 144000are distinct from the great crowd. As for the Church of England, they appear to have a postmillennial view.  Is your question aimed at the worldwide Anglican community in general or at the English Anglican Church?

Comment: Mat 7:14 says that only a few finds the path that leads to life. How many is a few? It has been estimated that about 107 billion people have lived on earth. Is 144000 (288000) considered to be a few in comparison with 107 billion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an Anglican Commentary on the whole Bible.  "The complete number of God's people....and that a large one (144,000 is the square of 12 a thousandfold) is being gathered together for everlasting safety.  The Church of Christ is spoken of in OT language....the tribe of Dan is not mentioned perhaps because of a Jewish tradition that Antichrist was to come from this tribe:   source:  A Commentary on the Holy Bible by Various Writers, edited by the Rev. J.R. Dummelow M.A., Queens' College, Cambridge